# Why don't arm-linux-gcc and aarch64-linux-gcc toolchains support sanitizers?

Tags: gcc, g++, embedded-linux

I'm developing a C++ application for an embedded system that has a Linux kernel running on an ARM machine. I would like to enhance debugging process by compiling the application with sanitizers. Unfortunately, the linker fails to find the corresponding library files.

```
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -fsanitize=address main.cpp 
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-ld.real: cannot find -lasan
```

So, I understood that the compiler wasn't compiled with sanitizer support. The same thing occurs for the 64-bit compiler `aarch64-linux-gnu-g++`.

Is there a specific reason that these compilers don't support sanitizers?